# view animation not working for shadowRadius iOS

Tags: ios, animation, quartz-graphics, shadow

what I am trying to do is to simulate a pulse around my button. I can get the glow effect to work changing the properties of the button's layer. However, I can not get it to be animated.
Here it is what I have tried so far:

```
UIColor *confirmButtonColor = self.btnConfirm.currentTitleColor;
self.btnConfirm.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;

self.btnConfirm.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
self.btnConfirm.layer.shadowColor = confirmButtonColor.CGColor;
self.btnConfirm.layer.shadowRadius = 6.0f;
 self.btnConfirm.layer.shadowOpacity = .0f;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.2 delay:5 options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear animations:^{
    self.btnConfirm.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
}completion:nil];
```

The glow appear without being animated;
I also tried to put all the code inside the animation and didn't change.
And yes, I import `Quartz`.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not clear why what you have isn't working (perhaps someone can enlighten us) but this works:

```
UIColor *confirmButtonColor = self.btnConfirm.currentTitleColor;
self.btnConfirm.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;

self.btnConfirm.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
self.btnConfirm.layer.shadowColor = confirmButtonColor.CGColor;
self.btnConfirm.layer.shadowRadius = 6.0f;
self.btnConfirm.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f; // Note: You need the final value here
CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"shadowOpacity"];
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:.0];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
[self.btnConfirm.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"shadowOpacity"];
```

Comment: Yes @clafou if I use CABasicAnimation it works. However if I use [UIVew animationWithDuration...} it doesn't

Comment: While UIView's `animationWithDuration...` supports a number of UIKit view properties (which are all documented under Animations in the [UIView doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)), it doesn't deal with CALayer property changes. So you are stuck with Core Animation for layer-level animations. You can still get the same delay and easing function, it's just a little more code.